# Magento 2 How to get category by url_key

Tags: php, magento2

I try to get a category in Magento 2.0 by it url_key.

Now I've got :

```
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
        $category = $categoryFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('url_key','my_category_url_key');
```

It returns me this error :

> Error filtering template: Invalid method
>   Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor::addAttributeToFilter(Array
>   ( [0] => url_key [1] => my_category_url_key ) )

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory
 ****** inject in constructor ******
 */
protected $categoryFactory;

---------
---------
---------
$categories = $this->categoryFactory->create()
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('url_key','devops')
            ->addAttributeToSelect(['entity_id']);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($categories->getFirstItem()->getEntityId());
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but in case anybody wonders...

All answers here use the ObjectManager. That's bad practice. The correct way to implement this, is as follows:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory;

class MyClass {

private $categoryFactory;

public function __construct(
    CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
} {
    $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
}

public function MyFunction() {
    $categoryFactory = $this->categoryFactory->create();
    $category = $categoryFactory->loadByAttribute('url_key', 'my_category_key');
    $categoryId = $category->getId(); // E.g. if you want the ID.
}
```

In this example, `category` will contain the object of the category with URL-key 'my_category_key'.

Answer (score 0):

`addAttributeToFilter` is a method of collections.
You should execute in on a category collection, not on a category instance.

Comment: Yes I see that.
Now how can I filter by url_key ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this below code, i hope you will get your result.

```
<?php
$objectManagerr = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$categoryFactory = $objectManagerr->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
$categoryy = $categoryFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('url_key','your_category_url_key')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach ($categoryy as $productt){

    echo $productt->getName().'<br>';
    echo $productt->getId();
}
?>
```

Comment: although code is buggy but idea is in right direction.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your code, you missed the correct method in order to get a category via url_key.
Right now we can use method **loadByAttribute**, so you code should be something like this:

```
$objectManager   = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$category        = $categoryFactory->create()->loadByAttribute('url_key','my_category_url_key');
```